# Как вывести дату в таком форате WP?

Tags: wordpress

Привет есть такая структура

```
<div class="date">
  <span>12</span>
  <span>апреля</span>
</div>
```

Как вывести отдельно день и месяц ( год не надо )

Comment: Какую дату? У всех форматы разные

Comment: Имеется ввиду разделить число им месяц

Comment: Ещё раз - вы откуда дату берёте? Покажите код php, где вы получаете дату в переменную.

Comment: @KAGGDesign классический вывод из WordPress

Comment: "классический вывод из WordPress" это ни о чем.Вилами по воде - см the_date() и тп.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно получить текущую дату, то можно сделать так:

```
    $monthes = array(
        1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
        5 => 'Мая', 6 => 'Июня', 7 => 'Июля', 8 => 'Августа',
        9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
    );
    echo date('j');
    echo $monthes[(date('n'))];
```